# Android - Extracting string from .java code to string.xml

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, multilingual

I know it's good practice to use strings.xml file for all your hard coded string, especially if you're developer of a ***multi language app***.
It's all good with **layout.xml** files, you can easily use like this: `android:text="@string/Login_text"`.
But what about **.java** files?
For example, what it's the ***best practice*** to get the strings (from separate file like strings.xml) from this code:

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progress.setTitle("Some Title In Hebrew Language");
    progress.setMessage("Some Message In Hebrew Language");
```

I'm using Android-Studio.

Comment: strings (to separate file) ??

Comment: You're right I edited it

Comment: you want those strings to be put in strings.xml?? is that what you are looking for.  if you want strings from `strings.xml` the below answers will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android:text="@string/Login_text"
```

and

```
getResources().getString(R.string.Login_text)
```

both are same. One is `XML` approach and other is `Class` file approach.

So write your code like this:

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progress.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.sometext1)); 
    progress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.sometext2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also define java string in string.xml

and you can use it like:

```
getString(R.string.string_name);
```